# Can I make razor recognize .html file extension as its own?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So I can use the designer mode? I'm relying less on asp.net mvc html helpers, but not totally ditching it, opting to use plain html (in which should have no problem being rendered in Design Mode) instead

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Write you own View Engine

```
public class MyRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine 
{
    public MyRazorViewEngine() 
{
        base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.html", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.html", 
        };
 ....
```

See System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine for the rest of the locations to include

Then register it on startup

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyRazorViewEngine()));
    RazorCodeLanguage.Languages["html"] = new CSharpRazorCodeLanguage();
```

and the following to your applications web.config

```
<system.web>    
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </assemblies>
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".html"          type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Upside - you get designer mode, Downside - you lose all razor highlighting and intellisense

Comment: You have this: `public MyRazorViewEngine(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator)`. Where could I get the viewPageActivator parameter for the `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyRazorViewEngine(???)));` ?
`?

Comment: Just remove it, it shouldn't be there =)

Comment: Forgot to tell, I already tried that(removing) before I made a comment, doesn't work either, razor keeps finding .cshtml

Comment: did you add all the urls from razorviewengine?

Comment: Yes, I add them all, including this: `"~/Views/{1}/{0}.html"`, still can't find

Comment: when I do it I get the error - There is no build provider registered for the extension '.html'. You can register one in the <compilation><buildProviders> section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.